# How to check if the last char of a String is a specific char

Tags: java

I have a funtion in my program that should determine if the last char of a string is a / and if not, add a / at the end, however, it always adds a /, even if the last char is a /
Here is the code:

```
public static String setLastCharSlash(String check) {
    if(check.substring(check.length() - 1) != "/") {
        check = check + "/";
    }
    return check;
}
```

Comment: `return check.endsWith("/") ? check : (check + "/");` is better: it avoids creating a new string unnecessarily.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "How do I compare strings in Java?". It's an unrelated question how to chat the value of the last character.

Comment: The problem is that != compares the two objects and checks whether they are the same, but they are just similar. To check similarity instead, use the .equals() function, like this: check.substring(check.length() - 1).equals("/")

Comment: @SteveKuo the problem here is they compare strings incorrectly so it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a specific method for this use case:

```
boolean isSlashLast = "your/string/".endsWith("/");
```